# Can't schedule refresh for this dataset in Power BI service

Tags: powerbi, vnet, data-gateway, microsoft-portal

I used a Python script in Power Query to pull data from Prometheus. It works fine in PBI Desktop, but I get the following error for the automated refresh in the Power BI service:

> Unable to determine the data source due to unknown functions. When
> custom connectors are used, the error can happen if gateway doesn't
> have the extension enabled. Details: Query contains unknown function
> name: Python.Execute. Data source for Query1 Discover Data Sources

How can I solve this error? Can I use Vnet as a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi for this you need to install gateway and install python in that gateway machine with all the required libraries.

IF you are using custom extraction scripts using python, it requires a gateway to work properly.

ps:
If you want to schedule it, have to use personal gateway
**thanks, Jon**

Comment: Just to note, it should be the personal gateway that is supported for python